# Simple example of an non-cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

I'm very familiar with cyclic groups, but I can't seem to understand what a non-cyclic group is like... is there a simple example of one?

(edited... I had no idea that non-cyclic != acyclic)

Comment: In the sense of algebraic topology (group whose classifying space is acyclic), or are you just looking for groups that aren't cyclic...?

Comment: @Jason S A noncyclic group is not the same as an *acyclic* group, see the link in my answer.

Comment: just an example of groups that are not cyclic

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Your concern has led to the askers correction of what the intended question is asking.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, you are right. Then my answer is no longer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first examples is Higman's four-generator four-relator group [Hi]
$$
\langle x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3 \mid x_{i+1}x_ix_{i+1}^{-1}=x_i^2, i∈ \mathbb{Z}/4\rangle.
$$
This group is *acyclic*, i.e., it has the same constant coefficient homology as the trivial group.
For details see [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Acyclic_group).

Edit: It seems that you wanted an example of a *non-cyclic* group. Just take $C_2\times C_2$, which cannot have an element of order $4$, hence is not cyclic.

Comment: I can look at that formula but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Given the edit you made to address the earlier edit of the asker, your answer still has merit; no need to delete.